# GeoDjango query PointField by coords

Tags: python, django, geodjango

Is it possible to query a django model by the lng, lat values of a PointField?

```
<---example--->

Foo.objects.filter(bar=(-73, 34)) 

## bar == name of PointField in the django model.
## -73 == longitude
## 34 == latitude
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking exact matches with coordinates might not be a good idea. You should query with the distance from the provided coordinates. Anyway, you can do both. [From the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/), there are [many lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#spatial-lookup-compatibility) you can perform on PointField. You can use the distance filter like this -

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
>>> from django.contrib.gis.measure import D # ``D`` is a shortcut for ``Distance``
>>> from geoapp import SouthTexasCity
# Distances will be calculated from this point, which does not have to be projected.
>>> pnt = fromstr('POINT(-96.876369 29.905320)', srid=4326)
# If numeric parameter, units of field (meters in this case) are assumed.
>>> qs = SouthTexasCity.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt, 7000))
# Find all Cities within 7 km, > 20 miles away, and > 100 chains  away (an obscure unit)
>>> qs = SouthTexasCity.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=7)))
>>> qs = SouthTexasCity.objects.filter(point__distance_gte=(pnt, D(mi=20)))
>>> qs = SouthTexasCity.objects.filter(point__distance_gte=(pnt, D(chain=100)))
```

Similarly you can perform `exact` lookup.